# How should I go about this html form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a couple questions and problems that I need some help on. I am working on a basic order form mock up. I am trying to make it look similar to [Example Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjQkm.png)
I need it to follow these three following constraints;

1. upon clicking the 'order' button provide an error message if the client has not filled in any of the required fields (be specific with my error messages citing which box is in error).
2. upon clicking the 'order' button provide a different message if they have correctly filled in the required information ( "Thank You, #firstname #lastname, for your order.  Your total is $xxxxx).
3. upon clicking the 'clear' button clear the boxes on the form, I need to be able to do this by writing my own script.

So far I have the layout almost complete. I am a little confused on how to lessen up the padding between the actual fields and the form legend border. 
I am also having trouble getting the form to reset due to using two different forms in order to achieve the border for both. Is their a way to call two forms via a document.getElementById("myForm" & myForm1").reset() I know this is wrong just figured it was easiest way to word it. The other problem I am having is getting my function to go through and check that their is a response for each input and if not specify where the error is and then if their is no error it reports back what the total amount is by multiplying the price and quantity and then states their first name and last name.  Below I will post my HTML, CSS, and JS. If somone could take the time to help me out I would greatly appreciate it. 
*----Fixed the reset and got it to call both forms-----*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">  
    <h1>JS Order Form</h1>
</head>
<body>

<script src="script.js"> <!--links js -->
</script>


<form id="myForm">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
 First Name: <input type="text" id="field1" name="fname"><br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" id="field2" name="lname"><br>

 </fieldset>
</form>

<table style="width:100%">
        <table align="right">
        <table border="1">  
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Widget 1</td>
    <td>$5</td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Widget 2</td>
    <td>$10</td>        

  </tr>
</table>

<form id="myForm1">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Order Info:</legend>
  Price: <input type="text" id="field3" name="pname"><br>
  Quantity: <input type="text" id="field4" name="qname"><br>

 </fieldset>
</form>
<div align="center">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Clear">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Order">
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

```
 h1 {
    text-align: center; 
}

form {
    text-align:center;

}

table {
    width:250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();  //grabs form and clears entrys
    }   

    //function myFunction1() 
    // {
      //   var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value.trim(); //checks length of first name
     //    var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value.trim(); //checks length of last name
      //   if ( field1.length == 0 || field2.length == 0)  // if they are set to 0 then report alert
      //   {
     //       alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
      //   } 
      //   else                                          // if filled in report this following alert
      //   {
     //       alert("Thank You for Submitting");
     //   }
     //}


    function myFunction1()
    {
      var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value.trim();
     var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value.trim();
     var field3 = document.getElementById("field3").value.trim();
      var field4 = document.getElementById("field4").value.trim();
    if ( field1.length == 0)
     {
            alert("Please fill in your First Name");
            return false;
     }
      else if ( field2.length == 0)
     {
            alert("Please fill in your Last Name");
            return false;
     }
      else if ( field3.length == 0)
     {
            alert("Please fill in the Price")
            return false;
     }
     else if ( field4.length == 0)
     {
            alert("Please fill in the Quantity")
            return false;
     }
    else 
    {
    alert("Thank you for submitting your Order")
    }
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to separate your JavaScript from your HTML. You may want to do regular expression matching on the Client Side, before it's also validated on the Server with a language like PHP. AJAX is the way to go. Learn it. It probably won't happen overnight, so don't get too frustrated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I separated it. I have seen this AJAX pop up a lot lately. I will look into it.

Comment: Note: header `<h1>` should not occur in `<head>`, use `<title>` instead.

Comment: Thanks just realized i did that. Meant to put it inbetwen head and body. I will fix it up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For showing error messages, avoid using `alert`. It is not a good way. Rather keep some hidden text with the message and just control its visibility depending on the user's input. Like:

   `<span id="field1Error" style="display:none">Please fill in your First Name</span>`

In JS:

```
if(field1.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('field1Error').style.display= 'block';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('field1Error').style.display= 'none';
}
```

2. For showing a confirmation also, you can use the above method. Just create your message in JS by gathering values from the fields and put it in a `div` which is already in the page.

   `<div id="confirmMessage"></div>`

In JS:

```
var content= 'Thank you '+ field1.value+ ' '+ field2.value+ ' for your order. Your total is '+ 
    parseInt(field3.value)* parseInt(field4.value)+ '.'
document.getElementById('confirmMessage').innerHTML= content;
```

3. The `reset()` works good. If you want to change this then you can iterate over the fields of the form and clear them manually.

I hope this helps. Please ask if you have any doubts.

**Edit:**
To display a combined alert, use flags to keep track of valid and invalid fields and use `if` instead of nested `if else if` blocks.

Change required:

```
function myFunction1()
{
  var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value.trim();
  var field1Valid= true;
 var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value.trim();
var field2Valid= true;
 var field3 = document.getElementById("field3").value.trim();
var field3Valid= true;
  var field4 = document.getElementById("field4").value.trim();
var field4Valid= true;
if ( field1.length == 0)
 {
        field1Valid= false;
 }
 if ( field2.length == 0)
 {
        field2Valid= false;
 }
 if ( field3.length == 0)
 {
        field3Valid= false;
 }
 if ( field4.length == 0)
 {
        field4Valid= false;
 }
var formValid= field1Valid && field2Valid && field3Valid && field4Valid; //true if all fields are valid else false
if( !formValid){
    var alertMessage= 'Please fill ';
    if( !field1Valid){ alertMessage+= 'First Name'; }
    if( !field2Valid){ alertMessage+= 'Last Name'; }
    if( !field3Valid){ alertMessage+= 'Price'; }
    if( !field4Valid){ alertMessage+= 'Quantity'; }
    alert(alertMessage);
    return false;
}
else{
     var alertMessage= 'Thanks for the order '+ field1+ ' '+ field2+ '. Your total is '+ String(parseInt(field3) * parseInt(field4) )+ '.';
    alert(alertMessage);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: I agree that the alerts are a terrible way to get the message across. I tried the way you explained above and its much cleaner. However is their a way to do it with an alert and a nested statement. I am using this as a study method for an html class. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _alert and a nested statement_ ? Please elaborate this.

Comment: Something along the lines of using an alert if say field1 was unoccupied then it would tell you to fill in field1 then it would proceed to check field 2 if field 1 was filled in and so on down to the end. If all the fields were filled in then it would relay a message saying form complete or submitted. Thats what I was attempting to figure out with myFunction1() above. Thanks

Comment: I think your code does the same. It checks field1 and alerts if it is not filled. Checks field2 if field1 was filled and alerts for the same. In your approach, I would suggest a change, i.e, check all the fields irrespective of the input in other fields and display a combined alert so that user gets to know the mistakes in one go rather than trying again for the form to submit and getting an alert that another field is empty.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to go about that? Is their a way to just use independent "if statements and then only print out a final alert after it has checked which ones have been filled?

Comment: Is their a way to store what fields pass and fail? So say it runs the .value.trim on all the fields and states that field 1 and 2 are empty but the others are full. It would then print out an alert saying please fill in your first and last name.

Comment: Actually at the end it would just calculate whatever the cost was of the price x quantity and then prompt the user thanks for the order "firstname" "lastname" your total is "calculated amount"

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: Is their a way to make it so it does not say thank you for order if you only put in the first name? It lets you submit pending that only one field has information in it. Is their a way to isolate it to only let you submit when all of the fields are full? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to allow the form submission if only First Name (along with Price and Quantity) if filled and not if both(First Name and Last Name) are not filled?

Comment: If only the first name, last name, price, quantity is filled out will you be able to submit. So as it stands right now you can submit with only filling out one of the 4 fields. I need it only to submit and calculate if all of the fields are filled out. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I have edited the `formValid` statement. Turns out it was wrong in the first place. Thank you for correcting. Please check.

Comment: Never mind me. For some reason when I typed it i put "OR" instead of "And"! I knew what you meant and did the same thing!

Comment: No issues. Now I think it is correct. If it fulfils your purpose, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Again! I learned way more in the past few hours on here then I have all year long! I will post up my full code on with comments when I finish so others can use it!

Comment: Welcome! :) Cool. Keep asking, Keep growing. :)